# Abstraction layer between repository and data access code

Tags: c#, ddd-repositories

I try to isolate repository from actual data storage implementation. I have little problem to create some simple query with this abstraction.

Example I need list of orders with number of order lines in order.

Repository method returns list of OrderInfo objects.

```
class OrderInfo
{
    string Title { get; set; }
    int NumberOfLines { get; set; }
}
```

Data storage does not contain any field directly containing order line count so it must be calculated on the fly.

This can be easily archived with simple sql query (count + group by) when query is directly written into repository method.

If I try to create some kind of abstraction layer I got lost how to "define query without using any storage dependant thing with it including that it should return number of order lines for each order".

Or am I totally going to wrong direction?

Comment: Why?  THe purpose of a repository is to isolate the app from the data storage implementation.  Why are you trying to isolate the isolation?  Sounds like over-engineering to me.

Comment: Ok ... I have read that repository belongs to BLL but its implementation is in data layer (whatever it means in practice)...? If I have this class OrderInfo and it is placed into domain (because it is exposed to UI and UI does not aware of data layer) ... how data layer can know anything about OrderInfo?

Comment: @MystereMan The basic definition of layering is that you want loose coupling between layers; sometimes this means coupling only by abstractions.

Comment: @PeterRitchie - I know.  That's the point of the Repository, It's a simple facade. to abstract the data layer.  You typically use an interface for the repository and then pass the concrete implementation into your business objects via constructor injection.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow the usage of IQueryable in your BLL (which I think it should), then you can define queries as much as you want. One of the criteria your DAL should then pass for it to be of usage with your BLL, is it should be able to take an IQueryable, and use it to read some data. This way you can 'be smart' in you BLL, and the DAL will be abstracted.

Example:

- BLL - define it using interfaces. A generated context-interface provides you with all entities (=tables) in the system. The entities will be available with `IQueryable<entityType>`. The entities are defined using Entity Framework POCO's.
- DAL - an Entity Framework context where the context implements the interface you defined in the BLL.

Each layer is in their own assembly. The DAL is wired up using some Dependency Injection.

Remember, this is just an example.

### UPDATE

Read [this](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/) article about the onion architecture, which is exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: IMHO I don't think it is a good idea for a repository to expose IQueryable. On the surface it seems like a great way to allow artibrary-flexible queries but that makes it very difficult to unit test. I've found that implementing methods for specific queries that return IEnumerable it is much easier to test and maintain.

Comment: I have already given up with IQueryable! I have tried so many times to build up my own IQueryProvider just to notice that it is so complex task to do ...

Comment: I did not mean to write your own IQueryProvider. You pass the query to your dal which should be able to handle it.

Comment: I have long time ago read that onion architecture article but I have to refresh my toughts about it, thanks!

Comment: @Maarten - It's not necessarily bad to pass IQueryable to the BLL, at least in a small app.  But in larger apps, and apps where you want to test each layer, then it's a big no-no.  You are essentially tying the business logic to the specific DAL implementation (because different ORM's implement their Linq in different ways).